# how to uninstall the app or packages in the Home-brew

Tags: terminal, homebrew

How to **uninstall all the app in the home-brew** with out deleting the brew.
and I also wants to know how to **delete the waste packages or unnecessary packages** in my home brew.

Can anyone pls help me how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the ans but I wants to delete all the packages, did u know any thing like deleting all the packages in the home-brew.

Comment: thanks for the ans @joy Jin , but nohillside was already given the ans, thanks for you response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Homebrew packages can be uninstalled with

```
brew uninstall PACKAGE-NAME
```

Homebrew can‘t know which packages you don‘t need anymore, you have to decide yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,is there any way to do all uninstallation at once.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=remove+all+brew+packages might give ideas